# MySQL & Python: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

I've created the following database using MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE tutors (
id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(320) NOT NULL,
description VARCHAR(400) NOT NULL,
image VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL, 
applyDate DATE NOT NULL)
```

where the image column stores the absolute paths to images I store in my file system.

However, when I try to insert user-inputted data such as

```
arguments = ("Name", "a@gmail.com", "desc", "C:\\Users\\path\\to\\image.png", "2020-08-23")
```

using Python with the code

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tutors (name, email, description, image, applyDate) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", arguments)
conn.commit()
```

it gives me the following error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement.
```

It works when I replace each `?` with `%s`, but I've read that `%s` is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, so I'd rather stay away from it if possible. Is there a reason `?` isn't working?

Comment: You've read wrong. For prepared statements with the mysql.connector, %s is the placeholder, not ?. %s is subject to SQL Injection when it is not used as a placeholder for a prepared statement but instead used for textual substitution as in `cursor.execute("SELECT y from t where x = '%s'" % some_value)` instead of `cursor.execute("SELECT y from t where x = %s", (some_value,))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `?` placeholder only works with prepared statement cursors, such as `cursor = conn.cursor(prepared=True)`.

If you don't want or need to use prepared statements, use `%s` as placeholder. It's safe since their values are escaped and quoted before the query is executed.